# react setState seems to be cancelled by redux dispatch?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to enable a submit button when I click a checkbox and editing this existing component to use redux (I realize it's not great, I'm just trying to get one part to work before refactoring). For now the button is not on the page.

```
class Survey extends Component {
  state = {
    questionsList: [
      {
        key: 'q1',
        checked: this.props.survey && this.props.survey.includes('q1'),
      },
      {
        key: 'q2',
        checked: this.props.survey && this.props.survey.includes('q2'),
      }
    ],
  };

  handleChange = (e) => {
    const questions = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.questionsList));

    // Filter the question for the checkbox user interacted with.
    const question = questions.find(q => q.key === e.target.name);
    question.checked = !question.checked; // toggle

   this.props.setEnableSubmit(questions.some(q => q.checked)); // dispatches a redux action (defined in mapDispatchToProps)
   this.setState({ questionsList: questions });
  }

  render() {
    return this.state.questionsList.map(question => (
      <Checkbox name={question.key} onChange={this.handleChange} />
    ));
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => ({
  survey: state.users[ownProps.match.params.userTarget].survey,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => ({
  setEnableSubmit: (value) => {
    dispatch(update(ownProps.match.params.userTarget, { enableSubmit: value }));
  }
});

export default compose(
  withRouter,
  connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps,
  ),
)(Survey);
```

I'm trying to store the disabled/enabledness of the button in the store, while keeping all the changes in the local state (and only persisting in the redux store on the button click)

for whatever reason, once `enableSubmit` happens, in re-render fn `this.state.questionsList` does not have the updated `questionsList` anymore (so I can't click the checkboxes). However it works if I remove the dispatch call. It has the same behavior if the setState is not there.

It gets to the setState without an exception. It updates enableSubmit in the store with the value passed. It doesn't seem to matter which line is called first or last or if in a cb to the dispatch or the dispatch is the cb to setState (tried all variations)

Comment: Do you ever get to your setState or is there some exception happening in setEnableSubmit? What does setEnableSubmit do?

Comment: Yes it gets to setState without an exception. It updates `enableSubmit` in the store with the value passed. It doesn't seem to matter if it's called first or last or if in a cb to the dispatch or the dispatch is the cb to setState (tried all variations)

Comment: Hmm my guess is there's something going on somewhere else in the code, I'm not seeing anything that would mess with your setState in the snippet you've posted.

Comment: hmm I removed basically everything from mapStateToProps and it still triggers a rerender when I dispatch. Is that normal?

Comment: Does your mapStateToProps take only dispatch or dispatch and ownProps? If it takes ownProps aswell, then yes it's normal.

Comment: oh yes, it does take ownProps, but there's no change in the props

Comment: It will always re-render no matter what if you take a second parameter, from the docs: "If your mapDispatchToProps function is declared as taking two parameters, it will be called with dispatch as the first parameter and the props passed to the connected component as the second parameter, and will be re-invoked whenever the connected component receives new props."

Check out https://spin.atomicobject.com/2018/04/02/redux-rerendering/ for a more in depth explanation of that.

Comment: I put a `componentWillReceiveProps` and I didn't see it fire, maybe I'm not understanding...

Comment: oh I see, thanks for the link

Comment: would need more code to see what exactly happens there. something is wrong with the code.

Comment: updated it. (I also still don’t understand why componentWillRecieveProps is not fired if mapDispatchToProps updates the props every time if ownProps is used)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the issue is due to the component rendering this child component. The parent component had a `mapStatetoProps` watching a slice of the redux store that was getting updated whenever I called `enableSubmit`, so the parent was receiving new props, rerendering and consequently creating a new child component instance based on our setup. So the multiple `mapDispatchToProps` calls and seeming ignore of `setState` was due to a new child component re instantiating